# Performance - How big is too big for an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, performance, optimization

I have a web app that's constantly sending and requesting JSON objects to/from  the server. These JSON objects can get as big as 20-40kb, and these requests might happen once every 5 to 20 seconds, depending on the user interaction.

I decided to keep my processing on the client side, so the user can use my web app without having to keep an active internet connection, but I need to sync the data to the server every once in a while. I couldn't think of a better solution than storing/processing data in the client as javascript objects and eventually saving them as json on a server. (this would also enable me to serve theses objectes with an API to mobile applications in the future)

I'd like to know how having these relatively large JSON data back and forth could make my application worse in performance, in comparison to just sending simple ajax request of a few bytes and doind all the processing on the server, and how could I make this more optimized?

Comment: 20-40kb in `request` might be little higher but in `response` i think its completely okay.

Answer (score 4):

`20-40Kb` size JSON objects for requests is pretty small according to tests done by [Josh Zeigler](http://josh.zeigler.us/about/), where the DOM Ready even took less than `62milliseconds` (MAX, in IE) across 4 Major browsers for a 40KB JSON payload.

The tests were done on a 2011 2.2GHz i7 MacBook Pro with 8GB of RAM.

[image: json performance test]

Here's the detailed test and test results: [How Big is TOO BIG for JSON?](http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/) Credit: [Josh Zeigler](http://josh.zeigler.us/about/)

Comment: Nice test! 40kb seems ok for download size, but what about for upload?